# How much damage (cracks) is acceptable on a national identity card before it won't be accepted?

Tags: paperwork, identity-cards, swiss-citizens

My Swiss identity card has a crack on about a third of its height, in the middle. I have no reason to believe the RFID chip is damaged. All information is still legible.

Here's what the crack looks like, on a specimen :
[image: sample card with overlaid crack]

Should I be concerned that it won't be accepted as legit ID when traveling abroad or when required to produce ID?

I tried to look for documentation of how much / what kind of damage is accepted on ID documents but couldn't find any. I guess this would be decided at the Schengen space level? If anyone has more success than I, I'd be interested.

Comment: Just an anecdote, so not posting as an answer, but when I tried to use my Polish ID with a ~5mm crack in a bank, they told me it's invalid and has to be replaced. I traveled with it once and no one cared, but probably they missed it.

Comment: Huh, I would have expected Swiss ID cards to be much more well designed than that. Kind of disappointing.

Comment: @typo Their driving licence is much more neatly designed

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just so you know, your ID does not contain an RFID chip.

As for the crack, there's no hard and fast rule as to what damages are accepted - rather it depends on the judgment of border officers in other countries. The fact that the machine-readable code is intact means it would probably be fine at Swiss land borders and other internal Schengen borders (if a check is performed that is, which is common when entering Switzerland by bus).

At *real* border crossings, however, such as in the UK, you would probably be delayed as your identity is examined, while in non-EU/EFTA countries such as Turkey or Tunisia, it's unlikely you'd be let in.

I would get a new ID if I were you, at least if planning to venture outside of the EU/EFTA.

Comment: Outside of EU, you will need a passport anyway.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Not everywhere